# resolve typeerror: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: typeerror

I am quite new to python, so maybe there is a simple answer to my question.
I have imported data from a json file as follows:

```
input:
with open('file_destination.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
print(data)

output: 
[{'Node': {'Construction': {'id': 'd9794e40-c894-5027-8576-b30a3eb3c95c'}]
```

I would like to be able to extract the data for e.g. id = d9794e40-c894-5027-8576-b30a3eb3c95c, however I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(data['id'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've run :

```
t=[{'Node': {'Construction': {'id': 'd9794e40-c894-5027-8576-b30a3eb3c95c'}}}]
print(t[0]['Node']['Construction']['id'])
```

And i get this output:

```
d9794e40-c894-5027-8576-b30a3eb3c95c
```

I assume this solves your problem.

Comment: That did'nt work either. I get the error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/main.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(data[0]['id'])
KeyError: 'id'

Comment: @cmeThat means the first object to access is not 'id' but 'Node', did you try my edit ?